# Instagram API media/popular

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

What are the queries we can use with `media/popular`. Can we localize it according to country or geolocation?

Also is there a way to get the discovery feature's results with the api?

Answer (score 1):

This API is no longer supported.

Ref : https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/

Answer (score 0):

I was recently struggling with same problem and came to conclusion there is no other way except the hard one.

If you want location based popular images you must go with location endpoint. 
https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/214413140/media/recent

This link brings up recent media from custom location, key being the location-id. Your job is now to follow simple pagination api and merge responded arrays into one big bunch of JSON. ***$response['pagination']['next_max_id']*** parameter is responsible for pagination, so you simply send every next request with max_id of previous request.

https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/214413140/media/recent?max_id=1093665959941411696

End result will depend on the amount of information you gathered. In the end you will just gonna need to sort the array with like count and you're up to go whatever you were going to do.

Of course important part is to save images locally rather than generating every time user opens the webpage. Reason being not only generation time but limited amount of requests per hour.

Hope someone will come up better solution or Instagram API will finally support media/popular by location.

Comment: Do you know how to get/generate the discovery feed

Comment: I don't thing there is a way to discovery feed. It's not even implemented on website version of Instagram so even parsing the html won't get you there. I'll look into it and tell you if I come up with something.